# How to get an element within an array

Tags: c#, arrays, indexof

I have a fixed list of strings, which I've put inside an array. I'm using `IndexOf()` in order to get an element out of such an array but that seems not to work:

```
using System.Runtime;

  ...
  static string[] Alarm_Names = new string[3] {"A1",  "A2",  "A3"}
  static bool[]   arr_Alarms  = new bool[3]   {false, false, false};

  internal static void HandleAlarm(..., string code, ...)
  {
    if (arr_Alarms[IndexOf(Alarm_Names, code)]) return;       // does not compile
    if (arr_Alarms[Array.IndexOf(Alarm_Names, code)]) return; // does not compile
```

The function/static method `IndexOf()` seems not to exist, although [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof?view=net-6.0) mentions otherwise.
Most probably this is due to the fact that I'm programming in C#, .Net Framework 4.6.1, which is not recent enough for the .Net 6 version of the mentioned page.

As you can see, I have a list of constant strings, I would like to make a list of booleans for each of those strings and in case a string is entered as a function parameter, I would like to check the boolean list for checking the value, and the function `IndexOf()` was the perfect tool for that.
Are there other simple ways? (Or is my analysis wrong and can I do something very simple in order to make this work, without modifying the version of my target .Net framework?)

Comment: No, that's not it: the method takes more than one parameter.

Comment: @canton7: your last comment is correct. The problem was that the mentioned page said "Assembly: System.Runtime.dll" which made me put `using System.Runtime;` while I should have checked "Namespace: System", having made me put `using System;`. Please put your comment with my remark as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Note that you will get an IndexOutOfRangeException when your code doesn't exist as Alarm_Name: IndexOf will then return a -1 which is not a valid index.

Comment: You're better off using a dictionary for this. Start with `Dictionary<string, bool> alarms = new Dictionary<string, bool>() { { "A1", false }, { "A2", false }, { "A3", false } };` then you can do this: `if (alarms[code]) return;`.

Comment: @Enigmativity: and what happens when the code is not present in the dictionary?

Comment: @Dominique - You would need to ensure that it is, or change the dictionary to a `Func<string, bool>` that has a default value if the key is missing.

Comment: @Dominique - I use this extension method: `public static Func<K, V> Map<K, V>(this IDictionary<K, V> source, Func<K, V> @default) => key => (key == null || !source.ContainsKey(key)) ? @default(key) : source[key];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IndexOf` is a static method defined on the `Array` class. Since your code is not part of that class, you need to prefix it with the class name, as you have done in your second attempt:

```
Array.IndexOf(Alarm_Names, code)
```

Other than that, the only compiler error in your code is the missing semicolon from the `Alarm_Names` field.

Having fixed that, your code will compile *(barring other errors in the parts of the code which aren't shown)*.

```c#
using System; // needed for accessing "Array"

class YourClass
{
    static string[] Alarm_Names = new string[3] {"A1",  "A2",  "A3"};
    static bool[]   arr_Alarms  = new bool[3]   {false, false, false};

    internal static void HandleAlarm(..., string code, ...)
    {
      if (arr_Alarms[Array.IndexOf(Alarm_Names, code)]) return;
```

If it still won't compile, you'll need to list the actual compiler errors you're getting.

---

**NB:** If you're using C# 6 or later, you could use the `using static` feature to make all `static` members of the `Array` class available to call without the `Array.` prefix:

```
using static System.Array;

class YourClass
{
    static string[] Alarm_Names = new string[3] {"A1",  "A2",  "A3"};
    static bool[]   arr_Alarms  = new bool[3]   {false, false, false};

    internal static void HandleAlarm(..., string code, ...)
    {
      if (arr_Alarms[IndexOf(Alarm_Names, code)]) return;
```

[static modifier | using directive | C# Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive#static-modifier)

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] Alarm_Names = new string[3] { "A1", "A2", "A3" };
        bool[] arr_Alarms = new bool[3] { false, false, false };

        Console.WriteLine(HandleAlarm(arr_Alarms, "A2", Alarm_Names));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    static bool HandleAlarm(bool[] a, string code, string[] A)
    {
        if (a[Array.IndexOf(A, code)])//false
        {
            return a[Array.IndexOf(A, code)];
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).